# Can't umount a device

Tags: umount

I was trying to connect my computer with box.com for have the cloud disk in my computer, I was following [this](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/automatically-mount-box-cloud-storage-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10/) tutorial.

The problem is, I did something wrong and now the device doesn't work and I can't umount it.

Now appears something like this:

[image]

Any form of umount it?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: And the output of `ls -la ~/.davfs2`

Comment: And the output of `groups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/fstab
```

In the open file,comment the following line with #

```
https://www.box.com/dav/ /home/<username>/box  davfs  _netdev,rw,user 0 0
```

Like this:

```
#https://www.box.com/dav/ /home/<username>/box  davfs  _netdev,rw,user 0 0
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running:

```
reboot
```

Comment: yes, it works! i'm really new at ubuntu,  thanks you!!!